# Incidence matrices of generalized quadrangles

Tags: co.combinatorics, incidence-geometry, finite-geometry

Is there somewhere a database of incidence matrices of generalized quadrangles that one can download?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.uwyo.edu/moorhouse/pub/genpoly/

Answer (score 6):

You can compute them with the *[FinInG](http://cage.ugent.be/geometry/fining.php)* package in the computer algebra system [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/). *FinInG* has available all the classical generalised quadrangles, elation generalised quadrangles (with a $q$-clan, flock, or Kantor family as input), and it shouldn't be difficult to compute the known Payne-derived quadrangles from the symplectic generalised quadrangles. Here is an example:

`LoadPackage("fining");

    gq := SymplecticSpace(3, 5); 

    matrix := IncidenceMatrixOfGeneralisedPolygon( gq );`